# PowerShell Remoting $Using variable scope

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I have folder c:\test where I have three files: “file1”, “file2”, “file3”

Following script:

```
$remoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName localhost
$folder = "c:\test"
$exclude =@("c:\test\file1","c:\test\file2")

Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock {    
    #$Using:exclude
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Using:folder -recurse | Where {$Using:exclude -notcontains $_.FullName}
}

Remove-PSSession $remoteSession
```

Gives the result:
[image: Picture 1]

However, if I uncomment “$Using:exclude” I get the result:
[image]

Suddenly exclude list starts working properly

Comment: I get: `New-PSSession : [localhost] Beim Verbinden mit dem Remoteserver "localhost" ist folgender Fehler aufgetreten: Zugriff verweigert`

Comment: ok, I have to be `Administrator` to start a `pssession`. Another issue: where do you uncomment, it is already uncommented.

Answer (score 21):

Just specifying `$Using:exclude` in the Where-Object cmdlet doesn't work because it is in a nested *scriptblock*.

In your case , the `Using:folder` works because it is a local variable directly passed to the `Invoke-Command` *scriptblock*.

But "`Using:exclude` is passed to a *scriptblock* for `Where-Object`, which is itself nested inside the *scriptblock* for `Invoke-Command`.

`$Using` allows to pass local variables to scriptblocks only one level deep, not to *scriptblocks* nested any further.
This behaviour is not specific to the `Where-Object` scriptblock, any *cmdlet* which has a parameter taking a scriptblock behaves like this when it is inside a `Invoke-Command` scriptblock.

Unfortunately, I don't think this behaviour is documented.

By uncommenting `$Using:exclude` at the beginning of the `Invoke-Command` *scriptblock*, you are effectively declaring the variable `$exclude` inside the remote session.
So, in this case, `$exclude` becomes a local variable inside the `Invoke-Command` *scriptblock* and can be passed one level further, to the nested `Where-Object` *scriptblock*.

That's why it works when you uncomment `$Using:exclude` at the beginning of the `Invoke-Command` scriptblock, it's a workaround for the behaviour of `$Using`.

For the official help information about this run :

```
Get-Help about_remote_variables -Full
```

Comment: see my answer to this post :)

Comment: In your answer you "$using:" the two variables in the outermost scope of the remoted scriptblock, which allows them to be passed into the & scriptblocks.  @Mathieu explained this well, I think.

Comment: In my case I get all three files when uncommenting `$Using:exclude`