# PowerShell Splatting the Argumentlist on Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, argument-passing, invoke-command

How is it possible to use the parameters collected in a hash table for use with `ArgumentList` on `Invoke-Command`?

```
$CopyParams = @{
    Source      = 'E:\DEPARTMENTS\CBR\SHARE\Target'
    Destination = 'E:\DEPARTMENTS\CBR\SHARE\Target 2'
    Structure   = 'yyyy-MM-dd'
}
Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -ComputerName 'SERVER' -ScriptBlock ${Function:Copy-FilesHC} -ArgumentList @CopyParams
```

Whatever I try, it's always complaining about the 'Source':

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Source'. The "Test-Path $_" validation script for the argument with
 value "System.Collections.Hashtable" did not return true. Determine why the validation script failed
```

This [blog](http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/tag/splatting/) talks about a similar problem, but I can't get it to work.

The same is true for a simple `Copy-Item` within `Invoke-Command`, example:

```
Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -ComputerName 'SERVER' -ScriptBlock {Copy-Item} -ArgumentList @CopyParams

Invoke-Command : Missing an argument for parameter 'ArgumentList'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.Obj
ect[]' and try again.
At line:11 char:89
+ ... ck {Copy-Item} -ArgumentList @CopyParams
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Would help to see what's in the `ScriptBlock` - assume that's what's pulling `args[0]` and expecting it to be a hash? Also assume that's where the error message comes from?

Comment: Thank you for the reply arco444. The `ScriptBlock` is just a function with in the parameters a `Test-path` on `[String]Source` and `[String]Destination`. After this it just uses `Copy-Item` to copy stuff. It works fine when passing them as `-ArgumentList $Source, $Destination`, but not with splatting.

Comment: If you try it with my last example of `Copy-Item`, you'll see it doesn't work. Not even with the dollar sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround, but you have to make sure that your `Advanced function` which is located in your module file is loaded up front in the local session. So it can be used in the remote session. I wrote a small helper function for this.

```
Function Add-FunctionHC {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param(
        [String]$Name
    )
    Process {
        Try {
            $Module = (Get-Command $Name -EA Stop).ModuleName
        }
        Catch {
            Write-Error "Add-FunctionHC: Function '$Name' doesn't exist in any module"
            $Global:Error.RemoveAt('1')
            Break
        }
        if (-not (Get-Module -Name $Module)) {
            Import-Module -Name $Module
        }
    }
}

# Load funtion for remoting
Add-FunctionHC -Name 'Copy-FilesHC'

$CopyParams = @{
    Source      = 'E:\DEPARTMENTS\CBR\SHARE\Target\De file.txt'
    Destination = 'E:\DEPARTMENTS\CBR\SHARE\Target 2'
}

$RemoteFunctions = "function Copy-FilesHC {${function:Copy-FilesHC}}" #';' seperated to add more

Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $RemoteFunctions -ComputerName 'SERVER' -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {
    Param (
        $RemoteFunctions
    )
    . ([ScriptBlock]::Create($RemoteFunctions))
    $CopyParams = $using:CopyParams
    Copy-FilesHC @CopyParams
}
```

The big advantage is that you don't need to copy your complete function in the script and it can stay in the module. So when you change something in the module to the function it will also be available in the remote session, without the need to update your script.

Comment: This part was key for me: $CopyParams = $using:CopyParams. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

One-liner, to convert a remote script to accept named parameters from a hash.

Given a scriptblock which you wish to call like this:

```
$Options = @{
    Parameter1 = "foo"
    Parameter2 = "bar"
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTESERVER -ArgumentList $Options -ScriptBlock {
    param(
        $Parameter1,
        $Parameter2
    )
    #Script goes here, this is just a sample
    "ComputerName: $ENV:COMPUTERNAME"
    "Parameter1: $Parameter1"
    "Parameter2: $Parameter2"
}
```

You can convert it like so

```
Invoke-Command -Computername REMOTESERVER -ArgumentList $Options -ScriptBlock {param($Options)&{
    param(
        $Parameter1,
        $Parameter2
    )
    #Script goes here, this is just a sample
    "ComputerName: $ENV:COMPUTERNAME"
    "Parameter1: $Parameter1"
    "Parameter2: $Parameter2"
} @Options}
```

What's going on? Essentially we've wrapped the original script block like so:

```
{param($Options)& <# Original script block (including {} braces)#> @options }
```

This makes the original script block an anonymous function, and creates the outer script block which has a parameter `$Options`, which does nothing but call the inner script block, passing `@options` to splat the hash.

Comment: Great tip! Thanks Ben! :)

Comment: Quite elegant solution :). Wrap your original (unchanged) scriptblock within a simple outer scriptblock that does all the unpacking (splatting). Reference here: [about_Script_Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks) (search for `call operator`).

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to approach passing named parameters:

```
function Copy-FilesHC 
{
  param ($Source,$Destination,$Structure)
  "Source is $Source"
  "Desintation is $Destination"
  "Structure is $Structure"
  }


$CopyParams = @{
    Source      = 'E:\DEPARTMENTS\CBR\SHARE\Target'
    Destination = "'E:\DEPARTMENTS\CBR\SHARE\Target 2'" #Nested quotes required due to embedded space in value.
    Structure   = 'yyyy-MM-dd'
}

$SB = [scriptblock]::Create(".{${Function:Copy-FilesHC}} $(&{$args}@CopyParams)")

Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -ComputerName 'SERVER' -ScriptBlock $SB
```

Basically, you create a new script block from your invoked script, with the parameters splatted to that from the hash table.  Everything is already in the script block with the values expanded, so there's no argument list to pass.

Comment: Thank you mjolinor, it does work when there are no spaces in the `Source` path. When there are, it fails (Ex. `Source      = 'E:\DEPARTMENTS\CBR\SHARE\Target\De file.txt'`).

Comment: If the path contains embedded spaces, then you have to pass an explicitly quoted string, just the same as if you were passing it as a parameter at the command line.  This is true in any situation where you're using a hash table to splat parameters, not just for this application. I simply missed that one of the values had an embedded space in the answer. You use the same hash table that you would use if you wanted to splat the parameters to the command if it was being run in the local session. I updated the answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced a similar problem and solved it by building the hash (or rebuilding the hash) inside the invoke by leveraging the $using variable scope (more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996816/powershell-remoting-using-variable-scope))

it looks something like this:

```
$Source      = 'E:\DEPARTMENTS\CBR\SHARE\Target'
$Destination = 'E:\DEPARTMENTS\CBR\SHARE\Target 2'
$Structure   = 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred -ComputerName 'SERVER' -ScriptBlock {
    $CopyParms= @{ 
        'Source'=$Using:Source
        'Destination'=$Using:Destination
        'Structure'=$Using:Structure
    }
    Function:Copy-FilesHC @CopyParms
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

```
$hash = @{
    PARAM1="meaning of life"
    PARAM2=42
    PARAM3=$true
}
$params = foreach($x in $hash.GetEnumerator()) {"$($x.Name)=""$($x.Value)"""}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is late, but I ran into the same problem and found a solution that worked for me.  Assigning it to a variable within the scriptblock and then using that variable to splat didn't show any problems.

Here's an example:

```
$param=@{"parameter","value"}
invoke-command -asjob -session $session -ScriptBlock {$a=$args[0];cmdlet @a } -ArgumentList $param
```

Comment: `@{"parameter","value"}` is invalid syntax of hashtable, have you realy tested your posted script?