# Passing hashtable and args to powershell invoke-command as arguments

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Normally one can do the following:

```
function example{
     param(
         $Parameter1,
         $Parameter2
     )
     "Parameter1: $Parameter1"
     "Parameter2: $Parameter2"
     $PSBoundParameters
     $args
 }
```

and pass parameters explicitly or by splatting like so:

```
$options = @{parameter1='bounded parameter'}
example @options -Parameter2 'will be bounded too' 'this will go into args' -Parameter3 'this will too','and this one also'
```

```
Parameter1: bounded parameter
Parameter2: will be bounded too

Key        Value
---        -----
Parameter1 bounded parameters
Parameter2 will be bounded too
this will go into args
-Parameter3
this will too
and this one also
```

I would like to replicate that syntax's behavior somehow when using invoke command.
Ideally somethings like this syntax:

```
$options = @{parameter1='bounded parameter';parameter3='this will too'}
Invoke-Command -Computername REMOTESERVER -ArgumentList @options 'will be bounded to parameter2' 'this will go into args', 'and this one also' -ScriptBlock {'block'}
```

I have seen this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36283506/12603110 suggesting to wrap the script block with  which allows splatting of hashtables

```
{param($Options)& <# Original script block (including {} braces)#> @options }
```

I'm unsure how to deal with the `$args` and explicitly specified parameters(e.g. `Parameter2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing stops you from deconstructing, modifying and then proxying the arguments received by `Invoke-Command`:

```
$options = @{parameter1='bounded parameter'}

Invoke-Command -ArgumentList $options, "some other param", "unbound stuff" -ScriptBlock {
  # extract splatting table from original args list
  $splat,$args = $args

  & {
    param($Parameter1, $Parameter2)

    "Parameter1: $Parameter1"
    "Parameter2: $Parameter2"
    $PSBoundParameters
    $args
  } @splat @args
}
```