# Pass a variable to cmdlet in powershell function

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

The function below is meant to implement blocked sleep in PowerShell
It gets the following error executing `Start-Sleep` cmdlet:

> "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Seconds'. 
>   The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value"

The echo prints the correct argument value, but the argument is not passed to the cmdlet.
I tried a local variable with the same result. Tried to cast it to string or integer - no avail. The only way it works if the number is hard coded

```
function BlockedSleep($numSecs)
{
    echo "Sleeping  $($numSecs) seconds"    
    $job = Start-Job {Start-Sleep -s $numSecs }
    Wait-Job $job >$null #this supresses job output to console
    Receive-Job $job

}
```

Comment: Take a look at [`Get-Help about_Remote_Variables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables) and [`Get-Help about_Scopes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes). You will also find [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996816/powershell-remoting-using-variable-scope) useful.

Answer (score 0):

The job is executed in another thread that does not have access to your script's parameter. You can either include the variable as a argument to the scriptblock:

```
$job = Start-Job {param($secs) Start-Sleep -Seconds $secs } -ArgumentList $numSecs
```

Or you can use the using-variable scope (PS 3.0 +):

```
$job = Start-Job {Start-Sleep -Seconds $using:numSecs }
```

Comment: The first one did work. Looks like my powershell is not v 3 so the second one returned an error. Thank you  so much!