# Run functions in parallel - use same variable environment as calling script

Tags: powershell, scope, powershell-5.0, start-job

We want to execute two PowerShell functions in parallel. We found that `Start-Job` is looking good; however, we don't know all the parameters the function needs, and therefore we cannot pass them all via the `-ArgumentList` parameter.

How to call `Start-Job` (or a viable alternative?) in such a way that the inner function has the exact same "variable environment" as the caller?

(edit: also all functions/modules should be present as well)

Comment: It sounds like the $using: variable scope might be what you want here. See this previous SO post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996816/powershell-remoting-using-variable-scope

Comment: _however, we don't know all the parameters the function needs,_ But the environment does at runtime? So why not obtain the parameters from there then? I hope you don't hope to manipulate the same variable via multiple jobs.

Comment: Nope, variables would be used read-only.
How to obtain the parameters from there in a transparent way? The called function should still be working when not called in a Start-Job-parallel-scenario.

Comment: IMO it sounds like you should rewrite the function(s) to take the appropriate input data as parameters rather than rely on the execution context