# Powershell 7 ForEach-Object Parallel breaks automatic variable when passed to invoke-command

Tags: powershell, foreach, parallel.foreach

Please advise, any insight as to what i need to do to have the variable passed successfully would be much appreciated.

This works successfully, but works on each FQDN in the piped list one at a time. i have 100+ servers, so this can take longer than one would think. like 1-6 seconds per server

```
    Write-Host "Confirm correct OS is installed" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black

    $FQDNs | ForEach-Object {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock { 
            $OS = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption
            Write-Host "$Using:_`: $OS" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
            Write-Output "$Using:_`: $OS"
        }
    }
}
```

if i add the -Parallel parameter, it fails immediately with the error below. How else am i supposed to give the variable if an automatic variable is the only way I'm seeing that foreach-object pipes them? (I'm hoping that's wrong)

```
ForEach-Object: C:\Scripts\Checklist.ps1:53
Line |
  53 |      $FQDNs | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
     |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The value of the using variable '$using:_' cannot be retrieved because
     | it has not been set in the local session.
```

Here's the script with the Parallel parameter inserted to show exactly where i'm doing that

```
    Write-Host "Confirm correct OS is installed" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black

    $FQDNs | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock { 
            $OS = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Caption
            Write-Host "$Using:_`: $OS" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
            Write-Output "$Using:_`: $OS"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke-command computername comp1,comp2,comp3 already runs in parallel.

```
# elevated prompt
start-service winrm
invoke-command localhost,localhost,localhost { sleep 10 } 
(get-history)[-1] | fl

Id                 : 3
CommandLine        :     invoke-command localhost,localhost,localhost { sleep 10 }
ExecutionStatus    : Completed
StartExecutionTime : 6/19/2020 10:05:02 AM
EndExecutionTime   : 6/19/2020 10:05:13 AM  # 11 seconds for all three
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is apparently that PowerShell doesn't always handle **nested contexts** properly, and in this case, because adding the `-Parallel` parameter creates an independent runspace for each script block instance running in parallel, the `$Using:` now evaluates for that runspace context rather than the remoting session context in which it was previously executed *without* the parameter.

You'll actually run into the same problem if you alternately use `Invoke-Command` with `-ThrottleLimit` and an array of computer names passed into `-ComputerName` to take advantage of parallelism rather than `ForEach-Object` with `-Parallel`.

To address this, try using `[scriptblock]::Create()` to build your script block so that the correct context is honored, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57748156/2528538).